# Codeigniter. How to return records where value of variable is more than field in database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have the following codeigniter model function:

```
function get_successful($project_id, $amount_backed){
    $data = '';

    $this->db->where('id', $project_id); 
    $this->db->where($amount_backed >= 'funding_goal'); //HELP HERE
    $this->db->where('published', '1'); 

......

    return $data;
}
```

I need to only get records where the variable `$amount_backed` is higher or equal to the field `'funding_goal'`.

How can this be done with codeigniters active record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be:

```
$this->db->where('funding_goal <=', $amount_backed);
```

Also see the [CodeIgniter User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html), search for `$this->db->where();` and look at `Custom key/value method`, there is following example:

> $this->db->where('id <', $id);

P.s.: there are two more alternatives: *Associative array method* and *Custom string*.

Answer (score 1):

you can use :
`$this->db->where("funding_goal < $amount_backed")`

`a < b  == b>=a`

```
function get_successful($project_id, $amount_backed){
    $data = '';

    $this->db->where('id', $project_id); 
    $this->db->where("funding_goal < $amount_backed"); //HELP HERE
    $this->db->where('published', '1'); 

......

    return $data;
}
```